Tengo este error de importacion al usar react-native-google-signin en un proyecto React Native con expo usando firebase

'"@react-native-google-signin/google-signin"' has no exported member named 'GoogleOneTapSignIn'.

import { GoogleOneTapSignIn } from "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin";


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
